# Merge/Combine/Join two Observable arrays in one array and display it using ngFor together in Ionic 3 app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, observable, ngfor

I am receiving two arrays using api calls in my Ionic 3 project. I want to display data from both of them in the same line, like this

```
[item1.1] [item2.1] 
[item1.2] [item2.2] 
[item1.3] [item2.3]
```

And not like this

```
[item1.1] [item1.2] 
[item1.3] [item2.1] 
[item2.2] [item2.3]
```

I have tried different approaches, such as using forkJoin as well as combineLatest which shows the first array fully, and then the second one

```
Observable.combineLatest(this.arr1, this.arr2).subscribe(
          (ValOne, ValTwo]) => {
            console.log(ValOne);
            console.log(ValTwo);
          }
        );
```

I display the combined array in HTML this way, but it doesn't have the right order

```
      <div ion-item *ngFor="let x of (combinedArr | async)">
            <h2>{{ x.name }}</h2>           
            <h2> {{ x.id }} </h2>
      </div>
```

Also, I tried displaying it in two columns of a grid, but it showed the same type of output

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col *ngFor="let x of (arr1 | async);">
            <div>
                1 of 3 {{x.name}}
            </div>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
            <div *ngFor="let y of (arr2 | async);">
                2 of 3 {{y.id}}
            </div>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
Observable.combineLatest(this.arr1, this.arr2).subscribe(
          ([ValOne, ValTwo]) => {
            const combinedArr = [];
            const length = Math.max(ValOne.lenght, ValTwo.length);
            for (let i = 0;i < length;i++) {
              combinedArr.push([ValOne[i], ValTwo[i]);
            }
          }
        );
```

Each item in combinedArr is a row, and is comprised of another array representing columns:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let cols of combinedArr;">
        <ion-col *ngFor="let col of cols;">
            <div>
                1 of 3 {{col.name}}
            </div>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```